# Desabilitar botão ao selecionar item em DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho uma DataGrid com registros e um botão Editar. No momento estou fazendo o seguinte: o usuário seleciona o item da DataGrid e clica no botão Editar, para então ser realizada a verificação se ele pode ou não editar o registro. Gostaria de desabilitar o botão assim que o item fosse selecionado na DataGrid, sem ter que clicar no botão para então ser avisado que não pode editar.

```
private void btnEditar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGrid.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            if (Presenter.PodeEditar())
            {
                chamaMetodoEdicao();
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Impossível editar!");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Selecione um item.");
    }
```

Comment: Tu quer desabilitar o botão quando qualquer linha for selecionada? Ou quer fazer alguma validação de acordo com o conteúdo de uma célula específica? Poste o código que você fez no botão para validar se ele pode ou não editar o registro.

Comment: Exato, quero fazer a validação de acordo com o conteúdo da célula selecionada. Vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: Aliás, seu projeto é `Windows Forms` ou `WPF`?

Comment: Meu projeto é WPF

Comment: Você tem que usar a tag `WPF`. Editei para você. Vou mudar a resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em `Windows Forms` você pode usar o evento [`CellEnter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellenter(v=vs.110).aspx). Este evento é disparado sempre que você clicar numa célula (quando a célula receber foco).

Exemplo:

```
private void dataGrid_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (Presenter.PodeEditar())
       chamaMetodoEdicao();        
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Impossível editar!");
}
```

No `WPF`, você pode usar o método [`SelectionChanged()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.currentcellchanged(v=vs.100).aspx). Assim como o `CellEnter()` do Windows Forms o `SelectionChanged()` é disparado sempre que uma célula é clicada.

Exemplo:

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Presenter.PodeEditar())
        chamaMetodoEdicao();        
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Impossível editar!");
}
```

Comment: O problema é que não tenho o DataGridViewCellEventArgs no WPF

Comment: @Mathi901 editado.

Comment: Tive problemas com o evento CurrentCellChanged, estava me passando o valor da célula como nulo e dando NullReferenceException. Acabei utilizando o SelectionChanged e funcionou perfeitamente.